# serving files from a spring boot war file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've followed the guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) for turning a "hello, world" level Spring Boot app to a war file.  I can run this war like a jar and it will return the simple template.

What I don't understand is why I can't access a main.css file I've created.  I've placed it in the resources directory under "static/css/main.css" and according to the docs [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) Spring Boot will automatically server files under "resources", "static", "public", and "META-INF/resources".  However, when I build my war file and run it I can't query those files in the browser (like `http://localhost:8080/static/css/main.css`).  Have a missed a step?  If I peek into the created war file I see the "static" directory in "WEBINF/classes" right beside the "templates" directory and the directory holding my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files in `src/main/resources/static` are served from `/` so you don't need `static` in the path. You CSS file should be available from `http://localhost:8080/css/main.css`